# tablesorter not working in IE

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have something like following.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('#olah').tablesorter({
    sortList: [[1,0]],
    cssHeader: 'header',
    cssAsc: 'hdrAsc',
    cssDesc: 'hdrDsc', 
    widgets: ['zebra'] 
});
}
```

Workign fine in FF but not in IE9.The first colomn dosen't sort on page load in IE but after page load if i click on header then it works.Any idea.?

Comment: Could you provide a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with relevant code reproducing the problem ? (you can add ressources to link tablesorter plugin & css on the left). I created [one](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/bMdBr/) and it works ok in all IE.

Comment: can u tell me what are these attributes :  cssHeader: 'header',
    cssAsc: 'hdrAsc',
    cssDesc: 'hdrDsc',

Comment: uh? The ones you provided in your code example... check the [tablesorter documentation](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Configuration).

Comment: Let me get this straight... Before page load, the header doesn't work, but after page load it does.  Or, is the problem that the column isn't initially sorted in IE while it is in other browsers?

Comment: Also, Just for reference, the demo does work in IE9: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-sort-list.html I would confirm that the html structure is valid too. IE is very strict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options you asked about are as follows:

- `cssHeader` is the css class name added to the table header
- `cssAsc` is the css class added to the header when the sort is ascending; the default is actually `headerSortUp`.
- `cssDesc` is the class when the column sort is descending; default is `headerSortDown`.

Could the problem be that the `$(document).ready` function is missing the closing parenthesis `)`? I don't see it in the code you shared above.

Another issue that might be causing the problem is that IE is particular about case-sensitive names in ID's and class names. So if your `#olah` is really `#Olah`, IE won't find the ID.

If that still doesn't help, you'll have to share a bit more information, code or a link to your site because all we can do is guess.